# How to write new column with check constraint to allow only values Y, N?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

How to write new column with check constraint to allow only values Y, N ?

Comment: @Mureinik SQL Server.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal code to reproduce the problem. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `alter table` statement should do it:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD newcolumn CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' CHECK (newcolumn IN ('Y', 'N'))
```